# Build csv and upload to google drive in php (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel

How do I send a response()->stream() to google drive ? I'm not getting it because this method returns a class and not a file. My question is if I will need to save locally using file_put_contents() so that I can then send it to google drive

```
public function buildCsv($columns, $content): \Closure
    {
        return function () use ($columns, $content){
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);

            foreach ($content as $item) {
                fputcsv($file, $item);
            }

            fclose($file);
        };
    }
```

```
$cb = $this->buildCsv($this->CSVColumns, $csvData);
\Storage::disk('google')->put("csv-test", response()->stream($cb, 200, $headers));
```

On google drive my file looks like this:
[image: Google drive file]

Comment: Laravel has no default "CSV Service", therefore it's unclear what you're even talking about.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for letting me know, I added the method that generates the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function buildCsvFile($columns, $content): string
{
    $file = tmpfile();
    fputcsv($file, $columns);
    
    foreach ($content as $item) {
        fputcsv($file, $item);
    }
    $metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data($file);
    return file_get_contents($metaDatas['uri']);
}
```

```
$cb = $this->buildCsv($this->CSVColumns, $csvData);
\Storage::disk('google')->put("csv-test.csv", $cb);
```